# Downgarde CentOS 7+ to CentOS 6

Tags: ubuntu, centos, ssh, redhat

I've been doing some research and most of forum I've read so far say that there's no way to go down from 7 or 8 to version 6.
I did follow a guide and they said this notice:

Note: The following steps will only work for downgrades within the same major version (such as from RHEL/CentOS 7.6 to 7.5) but not between major versions (such as from RHEL/CentOS 7.0 to 6.9).

regards

Comment: why would you want to downgrade CentOS 7 to 6? is there any problem you need to solve by downgrading it?

Answer (score 3):

Such an in-place downgrade is outright impossible, unless you are willing to replace *every* single package and configuration file. The only realistic path is to install a *new* CentOS 6 instance, migrating all your data from the newer CentOS 7 system.

However, CentOS 6 is now out of support, so you should *absolutely avoid* such downgrade.